# Munkres Topology Lemma 7.2 confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The lemma which states that every infinite subset C of Z+ is countable is itself kind of obvious but when I read through the proof I could not figure out where exactly the fact that "C is a subset of Z+" is used.

My question is that can't we apply the same proof to every single set such as the set of all real numbers as well? (Assuming the well-ordering theorem is true that every set has a well order)

Comment: No, you can't. Because well-orders need not be isomorphic to the natural numbers.

Comment: I understand that, but when I am trying to replace the set C in the proof of lemma 7.2 with the set of real numbers, I cannot figure out which exact sentence in the proof becomes false. It must be somewhere in the surjective part but every sentence still seems correct to me if I replace the definition of C to be the set of reals (with a well-order).

Comment: I don't have the book, so I have no idea what the proof is. Try to work it out for uncountable well-orders and if you're careful enough you'll find where you're cheating.

Comment: The proof basically defines a function h: Z+ -> C for a set C where h(1) is the smallest element of set C and h(i) is the smallest element of set C-[h({1, 2, ..., i-1})]. It then proves h is both injective and surjective. The surjective part supposes c be any element in C. It first shows the infinite set h(Z+) cannot be contained in finite set {1, 2, ..., c} so there exist an n that h(n) > c. let m be the smallest number that h(m) >= c, then c does not belong to h({1,2,...,m-1}) and hence c belongs to C-h({1,2,...,m-1}). Since h(m) is the smallest element of the set h(m) <= c so h(m) = c.

Comment: Yes, and why would the proof work for any well-order which is not isomorphic to the natural numbers? How would you proceed through limit points?

Comment: That is the part I don't understand. let's say c is the limit ordinal omega-0 I know it cannot be in bijection to natural number but the argument that h(m) = c seems to work perfectly if we plug c = omega-0 into the proof.

Comment: I think I now understand it. The set {1, 2, ..., c} is not finite any more when we are trying to plug in c = omega-0 and all the consequent statements are false... Thank you for the answers.